# QuickBlox sometimes gives unauthorized error while signing in.Why?

Tags: android, webrtc, quickblox, videochat, quickblox-android

I hope you are all fine.I am using quickblox sample video chat app in android application .It works perfectly.But the problem is that sometimes when I try to login in my app or sign in then it gives unauthorized error,and then I refresh my android studio and re run my same application.then error is gone? What is the reason behind this? Does quickBlox free version is not efficiently to use? or free version sometimes cut off our connection? Please explain?

Comment: unauthorized error is not related to QuickBlox's limits, you should find error in your code. QuickBlox provides samples for checking main functionality, check your issue in this samples. Or provide logs with error (requests and responses with error) here for investigation your error.

Comment: same problem, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Authorization** error can be caused if
a user tries to authorize with wrong login and password or
a user uses invalid session token.

Check the [DOC](https://quickblox.com/developers/Errors) for other possible errors

Comment: but same code is working some time and sometimes don't..with same login..how is this possible?

Comment: make sure you have created blank session on first screen that launches. also check if chat service is logged in everytime you perform any quickblox query as below.

    if (QBChatService.getInstance().isLoggedIn()) {
// DO YOUR THING 
} else {
   // LOGIN TO CHAT SERVICE AGAIN
}